# gls Function in R: Fit Linear Model Using Generalized Least Squares

Tags: r, linear-programming, nonlinear-functions

"gls function fits a linear model using generalized least squares. The errors are allowed to be correlated and/or have unequal variances."

Example

```
 # NOT RUN {
 # AR(1) errors within each Mare
 fm1 <- gls(follicles ~ sin(2*pi*Time) + cos(2*pi*Time), Ovary,
       correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Mare))
 # variance increases as a power of the absolute fitted values
 fm2 <- update(fm1, weights = varPower())
 # }
```

I got all the above information from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nlme/versions/3.1-137/topics/gls

In the example, they used a nonlinear model "follicles ~ sin(2*pi*Time) + cos(2*pi*Time)". **My quesion is why they used gls fucntion to fit the nonlinear model?** Any idea please!

Thank you in advance

Comment: They didnt ; the model is linear

Comment: I thought sin and cos are nonlinear functions!

Comment: the nonlinear part means non-linear in the parameters. The example applies a transform to the predictors but they enter the model additively; similar to using `y ~ x^3` for example

Comment: For example: n=50
beta1=8
beta2=0.2
x=1:n*pi
error=arima.sim(model=list(ma=0.24),n=n,innov=rnorm(n,0,1))
y=beta1+sin(x*beta2)+error
plot(x,y,type="l")        ( The plot shows that the model is nonlinear, so can I use gls function to fit the model

Comment: fyi: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71437/distinction-between-linear-and-nonlinear-model